# How to set Working Precision in NIntegrate?

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a complicated numerical integration to do and I do not know how to deal with the fact that: "`NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small`". I need some help to handle this Working Precision which I have no clue how big it should set. The problem is in the choice of the elements of vectorj: if I choose 0.01, for instance, I get the result. However, I need it also for 0.3,0.5,1,3. dWtilde1 comes from fitting after importing a list, so I am providing the fitting function.

```
LcNum=1;
LNum=1;

Wtilde1[x_] = 
Piecewise[{{84.70844970934941 (1.358063302255057*^-6 + 
    0.000054264407745696725 x + 0.06120370445759003 x^2 - 
    0.03778051411806694 x^3 - 0.03480674514282874 x^4 + 
    0.08772020845229346 x^5 - 0.12984735652632778 x^6 + 
    0.1215430660500256 x^7 - 0.061742002368084664 x^8 + 
    0.013107545496998208 x^9), 0 <= x <= 1.0001}}];

dWtilde1[x1_] = Piecewise[{{D[Wtilde1[x1], x1], 0 <= x1 <= 1}}]; 
S1[x1_] = 
Piecewise[{{-1 + dWtilde1[x1]/dWtilde1[1], 
 0 < x1 <= 1}, {-1, -1 <= x1 <= 0}}];

vectorj = Flatten[List[0.3,0.5,1,3]];
vector = Table[
Table[Table[
 i, {i, 10^k, 10^(k + 1), If[k >= 1, 10^k, 10^(k - 1)]}], {k, -3, 
 4, 1}], {j, vectorj}];

Integral1tilde1[x_] = 
Integrate[(I*B*S1[x1] - beta)*Cos[M*(x1 + LcBar)], {x1, -LcBar, x}, 
Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals && -LcBar <= x <= 1 && LcBar > 0];
Integral2tilde1[x_] = 
Integrate[(I*B*S1[x1] - beta)*Sin[M*(1 - x1)], {x1, x, 1}, 
Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals && -LcBar <= x <= 1 && LcBar > 0];
M = Sqrt[alpha*(beta + I B)];
B = (-2 I beta Sinh[((1 - I)/2)*Sqrt[beta/2]])/((1 - I)*Sqrt[beta/2] *
  Cosh[((1 - I)/2)*Sqrt[beta/2]] - 
 2 Sinh[((1 - I)/2)*Sqrt[beta/2]]);

Part1tilde1 = -(alpha/(M*(Cos[M (1 + LcBar)])))*Integral1tilde1[x]*
Sin[M*(1 - x)];
Part2tilde1 = -(alpha/(M*(Cos[M (1 + LcBar)])))*Integral2tilde1[x]*
Cos[M*(x + LcBar)];
htilde1[x_, alpha_] = (Part1tilde1 + Part2tilde1);

IntegrandOFFtilde1[beta_] = 
Abs[-I (1 - (1 - I)/2*Sqrt[beta/2]*
     Cosh[(1 - I)*z*
        Sqrt[beta/2]]/(Sinh[(1 - I)/2*Sqrt[ beta/2]]))*(dWtilde1[
    x]) + (Z0 I beta dWtilde1[1]/
     2)*(Sinh[(1 - I) Sqrt[
       beta/2] z]/((1 - I) Sqrt[
        beta/2] Cosh[(Sqrt[beta/2] (1 - I)/2)] - 
      2 Sinh[Sqrt[beta/2] (1 - I)/2]))*(S1[x] - 
    htilde1[x, alpha])]^2;

 fExacttilde1 = 
 Table[Table[
 Table[i/(4*( 
     NIntegrate[
      IntegrandOFFtilde1[i] /. {Lc -> LcNum, L -> LNum, Z0 -> j, 
        alpha -> (gamaNum[LNum]/i)}, {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1/2, 
       1/2}])), {i, 10^k, 10^(k + 1), 
  If[k >= 1, 10^k, 10^(k - 1)]}], {k, -3, 4, 1}], {j, vectorj}];
```

Comment: If you mean the warning `NIntegrate::slwcon`, then `WorkingPrecision` is just one possible reason.  If you get an answer without any other error, it might be correct, since it passes the error estimation check.  Generally you set `WorkingPrecision -> 32` or whatever number.  `MachinePrecision` is about 16, but does not track precision; I sometimes start with `WorkingPrecision -> 16` and then double it, etc. If you cannot compute the coefficients of `Wtilde1` to a higher precision, you can artificially promote them with `SetPrecision[<expr>, 32]`....

Comment: The fastest way to find this kind of information is by clicking: `Help`->`Wolfram Documentation` and then searching for `WorkingPrecision` (or any other thing you have a doubt).

Comment: ...But you can check whether your integrand has working precision issues: First set its precision (with `SetPrecision`) to say `100`, then plug in numbers of precision `100` or higher, and finally measure the precision loss with `Precision[]`. Since `MachinePrecision` is about 16, if you lose more than half of this (or about `8`), then you can assume you have `WorkingPrecision` problems.  I usually set `WorkingPrecision` to be about 16 above the precision loss, when it appears to be the issue ***and*** simultaneously set `PrecisionGoal -> 8`.

Comment: Is this a minimal example (Do you really need the nested table structure to illustrate the problem?)

Comment: You have a bad definition for `Wtilde1`, it should be `Wtilde1[x_] = ...`

Comment: you have a number of undefined symbols in there such as `LcNum`

Comment: @MichaelE2 when I set `WorkingPrecision->32` I get `NIntegrate::precw: The precision of the argument function Abs(...) is less than WorkingPrecision(32.')`. How to deal with it?

Comment: I think I mentioned `SetPrecision[]` in the same comment....I'm not sure it matters, because I think `NIntegrate` will do it for you (successfully in this case). Only it complains about the inconsistency. It's probably better to redefine `Wtilde1[x_] = SetPrecision[<..your expr..>, Infinity]` or `Wtilde1[x_] = Rationalize[<..your expr..>, 0]` then you can play with the setting of `WorkingPrecision` without having to keep using `SetPrecision[]`.

Comment: There is an example at the end of this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127532/4999